# What is exactly this size of 'viewport'?

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

PPK in the article [A tale of two viewports — part one](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) says the viewport is the size of the window(measured by CSS pixel). And the width of viewport is the value of `document.documentElement.clientWidth` or `window.innerWidth`.But the results of these two are equal when zooming to 100%. However, when zooming in, the value of `window.innerWidth` decreases while the value of `document.documentElement.clientWidth` remains the same. So here are the questions:

1. How to get the size of viewport?
2. The article also mentions that the element 'html' is as width as viewport. I wonder if this is true when zooming in or out?

I would be really grateful if someone can answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. In CSS just use the units `vw` for width and `vh` for height like you'd normally do with `px`
2. After some testing I found out that when you zoom in the width of `html` shrinks. The viewport unit for CSS describes the `innerHTML` as well